# Dynamically create html table from an Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, vue.js

Hey I'm fairly new to Vue and JavaScript and I wanna create a Html table. For my software I wanne have a Table.vue component that can display me different tables like the following .

```
   {
        "id": 1,
        "text": "Hello"
   }
```

```
   {
        "id": 1,
        "status": "damaged",
        "info": "test",
        "text": "content"

   }
```

How do I get the columns of these different tables dynamically and how can I display them?

```
<template>
  <table class="table">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th v-for="(column, index) in columns" :key="index"> {{column}}</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
              <td v-for="(column, indexColumn) in columns" :key="indexColumn">{{item[column]}}</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</template>
```

```
 data() {
        return {
            items: [],
            columns: []
        }
    }
```

[table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Au8Je.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify both the columns that should be rendered, as well as the rows with all data.

The `Table.vue` could look like this:

```
<template>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="(column, index) in columns" :key="index">
          {{ column }}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(row, index) in rows" :key="index">
        <td v-for="(column, index) in columns" :key="index">
          {{ row[column] }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Table",
  props: {
    columns: Array,
    rows: Array,
  },
};
</script>
```

…and the parent component would then pass the data into `Table.vue` like this:

```
<template>
  <Table :columns="columns" :rows="rows" />
</template>

<script>
import Table from "./components/Table";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Table,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      columns: ["id", "title", "description"],
      rows: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: "what is this",
          description: "i like to describe",
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: "wait wat?",
          description: "i like to describe, too",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

See the [working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-jackson-ey6ye?file=/src/components/Table.vue).

Note that most actual Vue dataTable components use [render functions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html) for performance reasons.